# Regex in Java that can split special characters and alphanumerics

Tags: java, regex, posix

I was researching on using regex in Java and found something interesting on [this link](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm). It says

```
[:punct:]   Punctuation symbols . , " ' ? ! ; : # $ % & ( ) * + - / < > = @ [ ] \ ^ _ { } | ~
```

are used to break down special characters. Is there anything similar in Java, let say i have a variable:

```
String sample = "I have $100";
```

is there anyway i can break the variable: I have $100 as

```
I
have
$
100
```

Comment: Is `$` only character you want to separate? (I am asking since if that is true then I don't see any reason to mention `punct` class). Also is it always at start of some amount or can it also be placed at end like `123$`?

Comment: Hi @Pshemo, it can be £ or $, that is why i looking for regex param that can split all those symbols

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to split only on `£` or `$` I would suggest to put them in your own character class `[£$]` instead using predefined one which contains many characters that probably shouldn't be split. So try something like `split("\\s|(?<=[£$])")` which will split on

- `\\s` - every whitespace
- `(?<=[£$])` - every place that has `£` or `$` before it like `$|100` (`|` represents such place). Mechanism used here is called [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

Demo

```
for (String s : "I have $100 and £200".split("\\s|(?<=[£$])"))
    System.out.println(">" + s);
```

output:

```
>I
>have
>$
>100
>and
>£
>200
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the output you are asking with the following java code,

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\$)|(\\w+)");/*(\\w*)"); changed to \\w+ to avoid empty matches, based on AlanMoore's remark*/
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I have $100");
            while(matcher.find()){
//                if(matcher.group().isEmpty())continue;

                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative approach.  People always assume the OP is locked into using `split()`, when in many cases it's just the first thing they thought of, and they didn't know there was another--and usually easier--way to go about it.  But you should be using `(\\w+)` instead of `(\\w*)`; then you won't have to do that `isEmpty()` test.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks you are absolutely correct, i will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try, *look-around* regex,

```
  String sample = "£9999";
  String[] arr = sample.split("(?<=[$£])|(?= )");
  for (String string : arr) {
     System.out.println(string);
  }
```

**Output:**

```
£
9999
```

Comment: You need to get rid of the backslash.  You were using it to escape the dollar sign, but now you've gone back to using a character class and it's incorrectly escaping the opening bracket.  Also, why are you using that lookahead in the second branch?  It matches the space without consuming it, but you *want* to consume it.

Comment: @Masud, why is it showing 
    null
    $
    100
I don't understand?

Comment: @user3003233, For which input, you get this output?

Comment: input = £9999, and i get null at front, then currency and number. If i use $ or £ in the regex param, it gives null and then currency and number.

Comment: @user3003233, I don't know why you get null which I didn't reproduce. I may be the matter how you print the result. I have updated answer with output. It is ok at my PC.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple regular expression for this task is `\b`, which matches a word boundary. After splitting you need to trim the results and filter out empty strings, then you get what you want.